# C# winforms ListView columns min width

Tags: c#, winforms

I have several list view controls, each with many columns that I'd like to have the columns can't be resized too small passed the label size.

I know I can handle the event for column width changed but I don't want to have to do this over and over again, and all columns are different length of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows Forms ListView can be a source of frustration. I've heard good things about ObjectListView which is an open source replacement for the ListView that has an assload of features. Back when I was using Windows Forms I wish I had known about it.

Anyhow, here's a link that describes a feature that should do what you want.

http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/features.html#more-control-over-column-width